# Is there a way to reliably backup and restore a complex network configuration on Windows XP?

Tags: networking, backup, windows-registry

I have some Windows XP laptops (10+) that host a ad-hoc WIFI network connection to wireless PDA devices.  The laptop itself is connected via a 3rd party VPN radio network.   The radio network itself seems to be reliable.

If one small thing goes wrong with the network configuration then the PDA loses connectivity and so I need a way to backup a networking config , either via a script or a 3rd party program, so that I can restore a working network configuration if something goes wrong.   Is this possible?  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If it comes to network settings backup you can try:

```
netsh interface dump > config.dat
```

.. later you restore it using ..

```
netsh exec config.dat
```

Unfortunately I think it will not backup your wireless profiles. To do that you will need to look into something like this:

```
netsh wlan export profile name=_PROFILE_NAME_ folder=_FOLDER_
```

This will put your profile into xml file, to restore it:

```
netsh wlan add profile filename=_FILENAME_
```

:) and to display the list of profiles:

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

Good luck :)